# Script timed out before returning headers: application.py

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have been trying to deploy my flask app on aws using their elastic beanstalk service but I havnt had any luck. I have tried renaming app to application or import as application. I have tried adding different things to httpf.conf. But, no luck.

Any ideas?

Here is some examples of what i am using/running into.

```
[Tue Nov 29 04:36:57.477486 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28202] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Nov 29 04:36:58.593231 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 28480] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Nov 29 04:36:58.622166 2016] [so:warn] [pid 28480] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Tue Nov 29 04:36:58.627404 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 28480] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Nov 29 04:36:58.628967 2016] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 28480] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Tue Nov 29 04:36:58.664458 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28480] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Nov 29 04:36:58.667914 2016] [core:notice] [pid 28480] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Tue Nov 29 04:37:02.142727 2016] [:error] [pid 28485]  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[Tue Nov 29 04:38:05.392413 2016] [core:error] [pid 28509] [client 127.0.0.1:47208] Script timed out before returning headers: application.py
[Tue Nov 29 04:38:09.386271 2016] [core:error] [pid 28508] [client 127.0.0.1:47210] Script timed out before returning headers: application.py
[Tue Nov 29 04:38:13.392044 2016] [core:error] [pid 28506] [client 127.0.0.1:47212] Script timed out before returning headers: application.py
[Tue Nov 29 04:39:04.713037 2016] [core:error] [pid 28532] [client 172.31.63.245:56919] Script timed out before returning headers: application.py
```

application.py

```
from project_test import app as application
from project_test.models import db
```

project_test.__init__.py

```
from flask import Flask
from datetime import timedelta
from flask_mail import Message, Mail

from flask_login import LoginManager

from project_test.models import db, User

import os

mail = Mail()
app = Flask(__name__)

# app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])

app.config["APP_SETTINGS"] = "project_test.config.DevConfig"
app.config.from_object(app.config["APP_SETTINGS"])

mail.init_app(app)

app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(seconds=900)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
login_manager.login_message_category = "danger"

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.filter(User.id == int(user_id)).first()

import project_test.views
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because somewhere in your code you are starting the builtin Flask developer server. This is evident from the message:

```
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Usually this is because `app.run()` is being called, but that is not evident in what you have shown.

Either way, you shouldn't be starting up the Flask development server as mod_wsgi under Apache is acting as the WSGI server.

Comment: it was these lines that did it... app.config["APP_SETTINGS"] = "northtrack.config.DevConfig"
app.config.from_object(app.config["APP_SETTINGS"]). Thanks!

Comment: Those lines shouldn't start the builtin developer server which was problem I was highlighting. Maybe you hadn't restarted Apache after some prior change where you removed what was causing it.

Comment: You are correct. I added those lines in after restarting apache and it worked. It was app.run() that was doing it but i never restarted Apache. Thanks again!

Comment: just put app.run under... if __name__ == "__main__":